# C# dynamics throws RuntimeBinderException when accessing property

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm getting a `RuntimeBinderException` when attempting to read a property from a dynamic object.  This is no doubt one of those issues where I've not got the syntax quite right, but I'm just not seeing it....

Using a simple LinqPad script, the following works fine:

```
void Main()
{
    var response = new
    {
        DotNet = Environment.Version,
        ServerName = Environment.MachineName,
    };
    
    dynamic d = response;   
    var x = d.DotNet as Version;
    x.Major.Dump();
}
```

If I return it from a Web Method, then I'm running into issues.  Here is my simple web method (.Net 5 WebAPI)

```
public IActionResult GetEnvironmentDetails()
{
    var response = new
    {
        DotNet = Environment.Version,
        ServerName = Environment.MachineName,
    };
    return this.Ok(response);
}
```

In my unit test, I can read the property using reflection, but not using dynamics:

```
var c = new MyController();
var response = c.GetEnvironmentDetails() as OkObjectResult;

// This next line gets me the property using reflection:
Version dotNet = response.Value.GetType().GetProperty("DotNet").GetValue(response.Value, null) as Version;

// But...using dynamics
dynamic d = response.Value;

// then the following fails for me
object x = d.DotNet;
```

If I put the variable `d` in my WATCH window, then the Value shows as `{ DotNet = {5.0.4}, ServerName = "MyComputerName" }` and the Type is `<Anonymous Type>`.

Comment: The error message is: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'DotNet'".  I can get this to work if I change my WebAPi to use an `ExpandoObject`.  Just seems a bit unnecessary since the JSON response as shown in Postman appears identical.